# Nancy: serve static content in web root

Tags: c#, nancy

I have a nancy project which is to serve static content, located in `/my/web/root/`. I created a `IRootPathProvider` to set the webroot to `/my/web/root/`, but when I add the rule `StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", "/")`, "it does not work": the server does not respond.

I can also set the root path to `/my/web/` and then set the rule path to `/root`, but that is very ugly, and sounds like a source for bugs.

Is there a way to solve this in a neat way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to serve static content at the root of my web app I configure Nancy the following way.

```
public class CustomBoostrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions conventions)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(conventions);

        conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
            StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", @"_Root")
        );
    }
}
```

This will serve static content from a _Root folder in the solution but it will appear as at the root of the application.

> e.g.
>
> localhost:3579/text.txt
>
> served from
>
> app-dir\_Root\text.txt

Comment: for me this is working on windows but not on linux, any clues?